# map is not displayed on phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi i am starting use phonegap, i am trying integrate a position in google maps in my app.
I do not get to show, if I do it in a clean project works, but in my project not.
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ceifer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/ceifer.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/geolocalizacion.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAKmWHtohFZPTI7tjCPrYYFuEbgHRIrNRE"> </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Pagina de Login -->
    <div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <a href="#inicio" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <h1>Ceifer</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
            <div id="map"></div> // here load map
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Ceifer &copy;</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fin de Login -->
```

geolocalizacion.js

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError);
    },

    onSuccess: function(position){
        var longitude = -3.6038057000000663;
        var latitude = 37.1708286;
        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLong,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLong,
              map: map,
              title: 'my location'
          });
    },

    onError: function(error){
        alert("the code is " + error.code + ". \n" + "message: " + error.message);
    },
};

app.initialize();
```

Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: is your wifi connection enabled? Unfortunately the map isn't visible without wifi connection enabled

Comment: Yes, wifi is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to check :

- Internet Connectivity
- Height & Width of the div with id as "map"
- Are you sure onSuccess id getting called

Debug the the app with chrome developer tool, and check is there anything appearing inside div with map, also check the networking tab to check if there is any network issue.